# Change name of Facebook app after it is submitted

Tags: facebook

How to the change name of a Facebook app after it is submitted and is live ? I just want to make the app name shorter. So how to do it without changing the app URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the app name in the developer settings @ developers.facebook.com/*appid*/summary

Comment: I have few permission and submitted for review. Successfully using the app after review permissions. Would like to rename the app, do i have to resubmit for reveiw?